# C++ Как получить содержимое памяти?

Tags: c++, указатели, память, системы-счисления

Как я могу получить содержимое памяти по указателю, с произвольной длинной ячейки? К примеру, взять 5 байт у условного адреса 0xfff и получить какую-то информацию, представленную в двоичной или шестнадцатеричной системе счисления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Информация](https://codelessons.ru/cplusplus/ukazateli-v-c-podrobnoe-rukovodstvo.html) по разыменованию указателя ([Подробнее](http://cppstudio.com/post/423/) о указателях):

```
int a = 10;
int *ptr;
ptr = &a;
cout << ptr /*Вывод адреса области памяти, в которой записана переменная (a = 10)*/ << *ptr /*Сами данные, на которые указывает указатель*/;
```

[Информация](http://cppstudio.com/post/319/) по форматированному выводу в C++:

```
int value = 64;
cout << hex << value << endl; //вывод: 40 (16система)
```

Comment: Тогда уж `ptr = &a;`, только вот вы брали информацию не совсем о содержимом "производной" (как я понимаю, ТС так пишет "произвольной") ячейки. Что в общем случае - UB.

Comment: Да, перепутал, но уже исправил.